# If i = 9, why does the --i not print a 0 in a C while loop but i-- prints a 0 starting from 8?

Tags: c

```
int i;

i = 9;
while (--i)
{
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

The above piece of code prints 87654321. (This means the decrement happens first before printing as we have the pre-decrement sign before the i and we do not print the 0 because the while loop evaluates the 0 as false.)

Now, how come in this next piece of code, the output starts from 8 and ends at 0? (876543210)

```
int i;

i = 9;
while (i--)
{
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Since the second code has a post decrement, I was expecting it to start printing from 9 without the 0 at the end since the while loop in the first example evaluated 0 as false. Following the pre-decrement and post decrement rule, why is the second code giving such an output?

Comment: In the second example, printing __also__ happens after the decrement.

Comment: A quick step through with a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) could have helped.

Comment: by the time you get to the body of the `while` loop, `i` has decremented by `1` in both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 1;
while (--i) // evaluates to while (0)
// condition is false so the while loop stops
```

```
i = 1;
while (i--) // evaluates to while (1), afterwards i gets decremented to 0
// condition is true so we enter the loop body
```

Comment: infinitezero, thank you so much! This is the explanation I was hoping to find. Well understood.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two versions is how `while` tests whether to keep iterating. In the pre-increment version it tests the decremented value, in the post-increment version it tests the original value.

In either case, printing happens after the increment, so it starts at `8`. The difference is whether the `0` case is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Any loop can be written as an infinite loop (`while (1)`), moving the condition inside the loop as an `if` statement that `break`s the loop when the termination condition is true. The following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```c
while (condition) {
  do-something
}
```

```c
while (1) {
  if (! condition) {
    break;
  }
  do-something
}
```

Let's rewrite your first loop this way.

```c
int i;

i = 9;
while (1) {
  if (! (--i)) {
    break;
  }

  printf("%d", i);
}
```

But `-- i` means `i = i - 1` then `i` is evaluated. Which means that the loop above is equivalent to:

```c
while (1) {
  i = i - 1;
  if (! i) {
    break;
  }

  printf("%d", i);
}
```

And `! i` is the same as `i == 0`, therefore the loop becomes:

```c
int i = 9;

while (1) {
  i = i - 1;
  if (i == 0) {
    break;
  }

  printf("%d", i);
}
```

Now it is clear that the initial value of `i` (which is `9`) is not printed because `i` is decremented before being printed (if the loop does not end on that iteration). It is also clear that the value `0` is not printed because on the iteration that starts with `i == 0`, the `if` condition becomes true and the loop ends.

Similar, because `i --` means *"first evaluate `i`, then decrement it"*, the loop that uses `i --` is equivalent to:

```c
int i = 9;

while (1) {
  if (i == 0) {
    break;
  }
  i = i - 1;

  printf("%d", i);
}
```

On this loop, the value `9` is also not printed but `0` is printed because the last iteration that prints something starts with `i == 1`. It is then decremented and printed then the loop ends on the next iteration (that starts with `i == 0`).

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 9;
while (i--) { // 1
    printf("%d", i); 
}
```

1. `i` is "truth-tested" and decreased by one here. If it was tested with the value 9, it's decreased and will be 8 inside the loop.
   If it was tested with the value 1, it will be 0 inside the loop.

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you very much for making this clear. I have now understood it clearly.